# Xamarin update 4.2.0.680 today (2016-09-15) caused ColorTypeConverter.ConvertFrom(string) to throw a null reference exception

Tags: c#, xamarin

Today I got a warning when showing my students the code from the Xamarin book Chapter 8, ColorViewList program. I didn't think too much of a deprecation warning, but the program then threw a null reference exception on the following line:

```
Color color = (Color)colorTypeConv.ConvertFrom(colorName);
```

However, there were no null references. The warning indicates that ConvertFrom is deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually was quite simple to solve, Changing the line of code to the following fixed the problem.

```
Color color = (Color)colorTypeConv.ConvertFromInvariantString(colorName);
```

Interestingly the documentation (https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ColorTypeConverter/) doesn't indicate the solution nor that the ConvertFrom method is deprecated. However the warning does give a hint to the solution. Hope that helps somebody - and hopefully the documentation gets updated soon.